# I am getting error about X11 library

Tags: compiling, c++, libraries, cmake

when I run cmake build I get this error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/Macros.cmake:296 (message):
  Missing item in X11_X11_LIB;X11_Xrandr_LIB
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/SFML/Window/CMakeLists.txt:239 (sfml_find_package)
```

I have already installed x11 library and I have even added /usr/lib path to FindX11.cmake.
Btw I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and this whole concept with cmake is still pretty new for me, so when possible give me as detailed instructions as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install related [development](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=x11.pc) [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=Xrandr.a) by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxrandr-dev
```

Comment: Yes, right. Thanks.